# Nginx rewrite if is not 'www'

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, subdomain, server, conditional-statements

Nginx rewrite: if is not www,

I can receive $sub variable with this:

```
~^(?<sub>.*)\.domain\.ec$
```

but im need to condition if not www, rewrite to
domain.ec/$sub

the conditions is the problem.

Comment: Just declare separate server for `www.domain.ec`

Comment: im understand what you saym im need to write, subdomain as path, like content.domain.ec to domain.ec/content

Comment: perfect!, yes only need to create a other file with the other rules and dont need to create condition, thanks!.